# What is non blocking and blocking future in Scala?

Tags: scala, async-await, future, nonblocking

I am using play framework , i read that Play handles every request in non blocking way.
So what is the difference between Blocking & Non Blocking Future in Scala?

Also please provide information about Future & Await.Result() method
Thanks !!!

Comment: A beginner-friendly guide to futures (3 years old, but still valid) can be found here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Answer (score 7):

If `Await.Result()` is called at any point before the `Future` has completed, the `Future` becomes blocking. If you instead use `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, `map`, or `flatMap` (and some other methods), you are registering a callback function that will occur when the `Future` returns. Thus, the `Future` is non-blocking. Use non-blocking `Future`s with callbacks whenever possible.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Scala. Does this mean that Await blocks the executing thread? I'm not understanding the language "the Future becomes blocking".

Comment: Yes, the executing thread is blocked until the awaited `Future` completes

Comment: Thanks. That helps. Now I'm trying to understand if, aside from `Await.result`, is there something that one can do within <MyCode> in the Future, i.e., within Future { <MyCode> } that will cause (say, unintentionally), the Future to block? E.g., say if I use Java blocking file read calls within <MyCode>. Will that cause the Future to block?

Comment: The `Future` will block in the thread in which it runs, but won't necessarily block the calling thread. But if you have a lot of blocking `Future`s, the CPUs will be occupied and eventually the thread calling the `Future`s will face starvation.